# Symfony+mongodb+ODM get the records group by month , date format in db "2017-09-08"

Tags: mongodb, symfony, group-by, odm

Symfony query not working for mongodb+ODM, here is the query that i am using but something wrong to with the format.

```
$getRecordForMonth =                                           
        $this->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_aggregation_query')
        ->getCollection('AppBundle:project')->createAggregateQuery()
        ->group(['_id' => ['substr' => ['$createddt', 5, 2], 'count' => sum(1)]);
```

Comment: Here is the mongo query but while converting in symfony2,not able to do db.test.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: {$substr: ['$bookingdatetime', 5, 2]}, 
        numberofbookings: {$sum: 1}
    }}
])

Comment: @lalit-agarwal can you please help in the above query.